# rootScope variables are null after time

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, rootscope

i'm developing an app with `ionic` that should save some variables like `rootScope variables` at the login and reuse these variables in `http requests` during the run of the application.

My problem is that after some time `rootScope variables are null`, so this causes an error in the execution of the app.

I saved the variables in this way:

```
$rootScope.mail = user.username;
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thank's

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: try local storage instead of rootscope

Comment: i've edited the question @Mistalis

Comment: When is the data lost? Did you **reload** the page?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice will be to create getter and setter methods in a service

```
sample.service('sampleService', function($http){

  var hat = false;

  this.setUserAuthenticated = function(value){
    hat = value
  };

  this.getUserAuthenticated = function(){

    return hat;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happen because of one of three reasons:

1. You are reloading the page at some point. This causes the app to reset it state (Single page apps should never refresh the page)
2. You are using the `$rootScope.mail` as a parameter at some point and deleting or overriding the data it has at the moment. Can ve avoided using `angular.copy`.
3. It's being deleted directly at some point and you don't know.

Anyhow, the ebst practice is to avoid using the `$rootScope` at any time, instead create a factory to save and communicate your data or/and a storage mechanism (like `localStorage`).

Answer (score 0):

its better to store the variable in local storage and retrieve the data from local storage and use them.

```
localStorage.setItem("username",user.username);

 localStorage.getItem("username");
```